# How to send click signals through a transparent window as xeyes with Xlib?

Tags: c, click, transparency, x11, xlib

[`xeyes`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Foundation#xutils) [[code]](ftp://ftp.x.org/pub/unsupported/programs/xeyes/xeyes.c) is a famous application on X Window System. It is developed by X Toolkit Intrinsics (aka Xt). I'm programming in C purely with Xlib, but I cannot reproduce the same effect as follows:

**P.S.** I think it is absolutely possible to write in Xlib because Xt is based on Xlib.

[image]

How to send click signals under another window as `xeyes` with Xlib?

Make some changes in `XCreateWindow()`? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using non-rectangular windows is an [extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_extension). It's not part of the core protocol.

The `XShape...` functions are provided in `libXext`. So to answer your question is that it is **not possible** to do this with **only** Xlib.

There is some [documentation](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libXext/shapelib.html) for this library.

Answer (score 1):

The source of xeyes is available, study it. You want to learn how functions with the XShape... prefix are used there. Unfortunately the manual page (`man XShape`) is of no help whatsoever, it just list the functions without explaining what they do or how to use them. You need to learn by example from existing applications.

Note, modern application have better-looking transparency with continuous range from 0 (opaue) to 1 (fully transparent). It is based on a different mechanism.